# TypeScript で単一のクラスを import する方法

Tags: typescript

TypeScript で外部モジュールを使用しています。

あるモジュールの指定したクラスだけを使いたい場合にモジュール名を指定せずに済む方法はあるでしょうか。

具体例を挙げると、次のような形ではなく、

```
// mymodule.ts
export class Klass {}

// index.ts
import m = require('./mymodule');
klass = new m.Klass();
```

次のような形で使いたいのです。(これはイメージ)

```
// mymodule.ts
export class Klass {}

// index.ts
import Klass = require('./mymodule').Klass;
klass = new Klass();
```

単一のクラスしか使わないため、可能なら `m` のようにモジュール名を指定したくないのです。

可能でしょうか？また、どのように書けば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 単一のクラスしか使わないため、可能なら m のようにモジュール名を指定したくない

モジュールから単一のクラスしか`export`しない場合であれば、[`export =`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-export-)でクラスそのものを直接エクスポートすることで以下のように書けます。

```
// mymodule.ts
class Klass {}
export = Klass;

// index.ts
import Klass = require('./mymodule');
var klass = new Klass();
```

> あるモジュールの指定したクラスだけを使いたい場合にモジュール名を指定せずに済む方法

複数のオブジェクトを`export`しているモジュールから、特定のものを直接`import`する、というのはできなさそうです。[言語仕様書](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf)の"11.2.2 External Import Declarations"に構文定義があります:

```
ExternalImportDeclaration:
    import Identifier = ExternalModuleReference ;
ExternalModuleReference:
    require ( StringLiteral )
```

これに従えば、`import identifier = require('string');`という文しか受け付けてくれないので、`require()`の後に何かを付けるような余地がありません。

コードの先頭で1回だけモジュール名を指定してよい、というところまで妥協すれば、後で利用したいクラスをローカル変数に持つようにすることで、それ以降はモジュール名を気にしなくてよくなります:

```
import m = require('./mymodule');
import Klass = m.Klass; // var Klass = m.Klass; にコンパイルされる
var klass = new Klass();
```

Answer (score 2):

ES Modules 前提の環境では次の記述で十分ですね。

```
// mymodule.ts
export class Klass {}

// index.ts
import { Klass } from './mymodule';
klass = new Klass();
```